# How do I write my delete file method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, yaml, delete-file

I'm currently learning Ruby and working on a Hangman project. This is my first time working with File and YAML.

I'm trying to implement methods to save/load games. I have decided I want there to be a maximum of 3 save files, if a user tries to save a game after this they are asked to delete a previous save file.

Here is a link to my program so far on Github (apologies, it needs refactoring): https://github.com/d-zer0/hangman/blob/master/hangman.rb[hangman.rb](https://github.com/d-zer0/hangman/blob/master/hangman.rb)

This is the code used to delete files:

```
game_files = Dir.entries("saved_games").select { |f| f.include?(".sav") }
game_file = "saved_games/#{game_files[index.to_i]}"
File.delete(game_file) #delete file
```

When running the program, when I select a file to delete I get this error:

```
hangman.rb:49:in `delete`: Permission denied @ unlink_internet - saved_games/ (Errno::EACCES)
    from hangman.rb:49:in `save_game'
    from hangman.rb:113:in `play'
    from hangman.rb:38:in `new_game'
    from hangman.rb:25:in `start_menu'
    from hangman.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from hangman.rb:172:in `new'
    from hangman.rb:172:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone show me why I'm getting this error and how to work around it? I have no idea if this helps but I'm doing this on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Does user you're running this code under have permissions to actually do that deletion?

Comment: Yes, I am running this on an admin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#{game_files[index.to_i]}` is evaluating to the empty string and you're trying to unlink a directory.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a newbie, can you ELI5 (explain like I'm 5) that for me? What do I need to change?

Comment: I'll give it a go. :) The expression `index.to_i` is evaluating to an index that isn't defined in `game_files`. It could be `game_files` is zero length. It could be it has 1 entry and `index.to_i` is evaluating to 1 and you're getting back a `nil` value.

A `nil` value when put in a string results in "", so you only get the directory name being passed to `delete`. Deleting files is different than deleting dirs, so you're getting the error.

I suggest you put `require "pp"` in your file and run `pp game_files` and `pp index` to debug this. Good luck!